# error in wordpress functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am very new to wordpress, and I am creating one new theme for wordpress website, so i wrote some functions in functions.php file. but because of that code the admin panel is not loading. whenever i try to login to admin panel it is showing blank page. could anyone please review my code and let me know if anything wrong in that.
Below is my functions.php file code

```
<?php 
 //Add support for WordPress 3.0's custom menus
 add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );

//Register area for custom menu
function register_my_menu() {
register_nav_menu( 'primary-menu', __( 'Primary Menu' ) );
register_nav_menu( 'secondary-menu', __( 'secondary Menu' ) );
}

register_nav_menus( array(
'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'menu1' ),
'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu', 'menu2'),
) );

//Gets post cat slug and looks for single-[cat slug].php and applies it
add_filter('single_template', create_function(
'$the_template',
'foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ) {
    if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php") )
    return TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php"; }
return $the_template;' )
);

/**
 * Register our sidebars and widgetized areas.
*
*/
function arphabet_widgets_init() {

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Home right sidebar',
    'id' => 'home_right_1',
    'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>',
  ) );
 }
 add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );

 ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should belong on Code Review or WordPress.

Comment: try debugging http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress, it will helpful to catch errors in code if any.

Comment: try define('WP_DEBUG', true); in wp-config.php and see where the error is

Answer (score 0):

Look into these:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
  'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'menu1' ),
  'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu', 'menu2')  // get rid of trailing comma
) );

function arphabet_widgets_init() {

  register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Home right sidebar',
    'id' => 'home_right_1',
    'description' => '',                      // added
    'class' => '',                            // added
    'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>'                 // get rid of trailing comma
  ) );
}


 add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );    // call after function declaration, not before
 add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
```